# what is the alternative for deprecated method org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.realmUrl()

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-admin-cli, keycloak-authorization-services

I am trying to verify the AccessToken using below code -

TokenVerifier verifier = TokenVerifier.create(StringAccessToken, AccessToken.class).withDefaultChecks();
PublicKey publicKey = getRealmPublicKey(verifier.getHeader());
return verifier.realmUrl(“someStringUrl”).publicKey(publicKey).verify().getToken();

But seems a realmUrl() method is deprecated. Can you please help with alternative solution for this?

or can you suggest an effective way to verify access token ?

Comment: I found the source of the mentioned class and the deprecation comment. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/TokenVerifier.java#L358 I would not be afraid of this. If the method disappers, your code wont compile any more. What is your context? are you inside springboot? are you authenticating a http request?

Comment: I am authenticating a http request. I am trying to the verify the token with the public key of the keycloak server. Got below reply from keucloak people which helped resolved the issue -                                                                                                    take a look at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier#withChecks which takes predicates for token validation.
The realm check is performed by org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.RealmUrlCheck

Comment: if you have found an answer to your question, it would be good, that you post your answer as answer and not as a comment, so that other people can see, that the question is answered and that no futher help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **org.keycloak.TokenVerifier#withChecks** which takes predicates for token validation.
The realm check is performed by `org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.RealmUrlCheck`

The modified code would be:

```
TokenVerifier<AccessToken> verifier = TokenVerifier.create(token, AccessToken.class).withChecks(new TokenVerifier.RealmUrlCheck(getRealmUrl()));
PublicKey publicKey = getRealmPublicKey(verifier.getHeader());
return verifier.publicKey(publicKey).verify().getToken();
```

Comment: how can do this getRealmPublicKey ?